# Weird Issues with WPMU I Can't Figure Out

Tags: wordpress, wpmu

I know I should post this on the WPMU forum, but no one writes me back and I'm just trying to find a larger audience hoping you have run into this issue as well.

I have built a WPMU site for a client, and I am able to upload media into the Media Library and within a Post or Page perfectly. I thought my job was finished, yet the client can't upload any media at all. I'm located in Kentucky, they are located in New England (if that even matters). I had the client record their process of uploading as I thought they were simply not following my instructions for uploading, yet they are doing everything correctly.

When uploading a file it goes through the process of allowing them to select a file and it says it uploads it, yet when it is finished uploading nothing is in the Media Library or in the Post.

Video of the client trying to upload in Media Manager (http://www.screencast.com/users/CatherineWeber/folders/Jing/media/945d33fa-a752-45fd-9bc1-f76fc5a1814a)

Video of the client trying to upload within a Post (http://www.screencast.com/users/CatherineWeber/folders/Jing/media/b5c60e25-f0b5-40c0-a820-c2fc9eb00906)

Asking the client to disable Flash Uploader didn't work :(

Yet, I can login to the WPMU site, access their blog's backend and can easily upload a ton of files. I am so lost at to what the issue is here. I am running version 2.8.4a, and will try to upgrade to latest release hoping this will fix things.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using same blog and same username to login ?

Comment: I login as the Administrator. Then from there I can view every blog, which gives me the option to go into each blog's backend. Then from there I try to upload and works fine for me.

Comment: what about client ? , does he log in as Administrator ?

Comment: no client logs in with their own WP login, which brings them to their specific blog Dashboard.

Comment: May be his user hasn't permission to upload media files , I am suggesting client to try upload file via your admin username , and then I will be able to think about this problem .

Comment: client logged in as Admin and was not able to upload any media.

Comment: that is very amazing , I think there is a problem in IE uploading process , can he try to upload it via Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Ask the client what media exactly he is trying to upload. PHP server has "Maximum allowed size for uploaded files"(upload_max_filesize) option. So if this limit is set to 2M(*M stands for MB in php.ini*), but the client is trying to upload something bigger...it can't be uploaded.

Also check the filetype...I'm not sure, but I think wordpress has such a filter.

If even this doesn't help, ask the client to record itself what exactly is doing on his screen. There could be errors returned, or any other little missed, by him things ;)